# Java live video capturing/streaming

Tags: java, video-streaming, video-capture, vlcj

Is there any idea how to implement a java programm that captures video/audio from a webcam
/microphone and stream it to multiple clients. I know about JMF but it is quite old and not well document or supported.

Comment: openCV is another choice. Please visit http://opencv.org/ for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a very good way via vlcj. Vlcj is a java wrapper for vlc.

Comment: -1 for being very helpful. can't find a single thing on google on how to actually use vlcj